# Проблема с отступами между Div'ми

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, отступы

Суть проблемы : Есть 2 дива (Content и footer). Мне бы хотелось добавить margin-bottom к "Content", но что-бы отступ был от "Footer", а у меня получается отступ от края страницы, что в итоге поднимает "footer" вверх. Так же, если есть возможность, подскажите как сделать так, что бы при расширении блока "Content" он сдвигал "footer" вниз и появлялся был скролл.(место этого он просто залезает на "Footer")

Comment: пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш код, чтобы можно было увидеть его и текущую проблему.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так можно сделать привязанный к низу подвал с отступом от контента: http://jsfiddle.net/p37h725j/
Элемент `content-gap` должен иметь размер подвала + некий отступ.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.content-gap {
    height: 70px;
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    Контент страницы
    
    <div class="content-gap"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Подвал привязанный к низу</div>
```